# Find all SKU products with tier price?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, database, select

I want to compare products with tier prices from two databases. From database Magento 1 and Magento 2. Compare them to generate a list of products from Magento 1 that do not have tier prices in Magento 2 and import these products.
I wrote a comparison script in js, but how can I form a query in the database to find all SKU products?
Please help me with a MySQL query to select all products with tier prices for Magento 1 and Magento 2.

```
let test1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4/2', '5/4', '6-2'];
let test2 = ['1', '2', '3', '5/4', '4/2', '6-1', '7/2', '8-2'];


const diff = function(arr1, arr2) {
  const set = new Set(arr2);
  return arr1.filter(n => !set.has(n));
}

console.log(diff(test1, test2));
```

If I get all products from select catalog_product_entity_tier_price I get the only id. But I need SKU

```
select DISTINCT (entity_id ) from catalog_product_entity_tier_price
```

I tried that but its don't work

```
SELECT catalog_product_entity_tier_price.entity_id, catalog_product_entity.sku FROM catalog_product_entity_tier_price
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity_tier_price.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.sku
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT catalog_product_entity_tier_price.entity_id, catalog_product_entity.sku FROM catalog_product_entity_tier_price
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity_tier_price.entity_id = catalog_product_entity.entity_id
```

Check the ON clause in the above. `catalog_product_entity.sku` won't give you (correct) matches.

Also I would use table aliasses to make it more readable:

```
SELECT cpetp.entity_id, cpe.sku 
FROM catalog_product_entity_tier_price cpetp
INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity cpe ON cpetp.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
```